# Azure WebJobs: There is not enough space on the disk

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I've tried zipping up a console app and uploading it to Azure as a WebJob, as I've done with others, but the upload fails. No explanation is given.

So then I tried FTPing it up there. I put it in

```
/site/wwwroot/App_Data/jobs/triggered/FeedbackNotifications
```

Where "FeedbackNotifications" is the name of my WebJob. I took the path from [this site](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/74215124623/deploy-azure-webjobs/#.VVyoq0a70us).

The upload completes and I can see the WebJob listed in the Azure portal. However, when I click "Run once" it fails. The log file contains the following:

> [05/20/2015 15:26:22 > e5f596: SYS INFO] Status changed to
>   Initializing
>
> [05/20/2015 15:26:23 > e5f596: SYS INFO] Status changed
>   to Failed
>
> [05/20/2015 15:26:23 > e5f596: SYS ERR ] Failed to copy job
>   files: System.IO.IOException: There is not enough space on the disk.
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
>   maybeFullPath)    at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String
>   sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean
>   checkHost)    at System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String
>   destFileName, Boolean overwrite)    at
>   System.IO.Abstractions.FileWrapper.Copy(String sourceFileName, String
>   destFileName, Boolean overwrite)    at
>   Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.FileSystemHelpers.CopyDirectoryRecursive(String
>   sourceDirPath, String destinationDirPath, Boolean overwrite)    at
>   Kudu.Core.Jobs.BaseJobRunner.b__0()    at
>   Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.OperationManager.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
>   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.OperationManager.Attempt[T](Func`1 action,
>   Int32 retries, Int32 delayBeforeRetry, Func`2 shouldRetry)    at
>   Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.OperationManager.Attempt(Action action, Int32
>   retries, Int32 delayBeforeRetry)    at
>   Kudu.Core.Jobs.BaseJobRunner.CacheJobBinaries(JobBase job, IJobLogger
>   logger) [05/20/2015 15:26:23 > e5f596: SYS INFO] Status changed to
>   Failed [05/20/2015 15:26:23 > e5f596: SYS ERR ] WebJob run failed due
>   to: System.InvalidOperationException: Missing working directory    at
>   Kudu.Core.Jobs.BaseJobRunner.InitializeJobInstance(JobBase job,
>   IJobLogger logger)    at
>   Kudu.Core.Jobs.TriggeredJobRunner.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0(Object
>   _)

The total size of the directory that contains everything is 115MB.

I've also read [this page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/987) which suggests that long file names may be the cause of the fault, but I've no file names longer 69 characters.

**UPDATE**: I've noticed that when I try an additional WebJob which previously worked, it incurs the same error.

Comment: Are you using a free site?

Comment: No, it's part of our MSDN subscription with unlimited spending.

Comment: But is the site itself a free site? (sku of the plan the site is using)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the WebJob is invoked the first time (or when its binaries are updated), it is first copied to the `%TEMP%` directory and will run from there.

Free (sku) azure websites have a limited amount of disk space in the Temp directory (actually in `d:\local`) which is 500MB.
It seems you have reached it and so WebJob fails to start.

To verify you can go to your scm site's debug console (https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole) and query for the free space on `d:\local` (`pushd d:\local` or clicking on the *Earth* button).

Comment: That's very likely the cause. I just re-configured the site from "Free" to "Basic" and it ran (it then failed but due to an exception in my code). Is it the case that repeated uploads with minor code changes count successively as 'first runs'? Otherwise why would it run and only incur the error after several modified-and-re-upload?  Also, if I delete the WebJob, does that also delete from `%TEMP%`?

Comment: The WebJob is deleted from `%TEMP%` but on a best effort, so there may be some remainaing files there, a restart to the site will remove the TEMP directory, also you can browse to it and see what is there.

Comment: How to query for free space?

Comment: How to query for free space: df -h