# Azure WebJob: There is not enough space on the disk

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

I am getting an error on my Azure WebJob about not being enough space on the disk. I had it earlier, so I moved it to `Standard 1` which says it comes with 50GB.

Here is the error I get:

```
[08/29/2019 05:19:04 > cd1c7c: SYS ERR ] Failed to copy job files: System.IO.IOException: There is not enough space on the disk.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.FileSystemHelpers.CopyDirectoryRecursive(String sourceDirPath, String destinationDirPath, Boolean overwrite) in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Infrastructure\FileSystemHelpers.cs:line 241
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.FileSystemHelpers.CopyDirectoryRecursive(String sourceDirPath, String destinationDirPath, Boolean overwrite) in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Infrastructure\FileSystemHelpers.cs:line 235
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.FileSystemHelpers.CopyDirectoryRecursive(String sourceDirPath, String destinationDirPath, Boolean overwrite) in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Infrastructure\FileSystemHelpers.cs:line 235
   at Kudu.Core.Jobs.BaseJobRunner.<>c__DisplayClass49_0.<CacheJobBinaries>b__0() in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Jobs\BaseJobRunner.cs:line 188
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.OperationManager.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Attempt>b__0() in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Infrastructure\OperationManager.cs:line 17
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.OperationManager.Attempt[T](Func`1 action, Int32 retries, Int32 delayBeforeRetry, Func`2 shouldRetry) in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Infrastructure\OperationManager.cs:line 42
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.OperationManager.Attempt(Action action, Int32 retries, Int32 delayBeforeRetry) in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Infrastructure\OperationManager.cs:line 19
   at Kudu.Core.Jobs.BaseJobRunner.CacheJobBinaries(JobBase job, IJobLogger logger) in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Jobs\BaseJobRunner.cs:line 179
[08/29/2019 05:19:06 > cd1c7c: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
[08/29/2019 05:19:06 > cd1c7c: SYS ERR ] WebJob run failed due to: System.InvalidOperationException: Missing working directory
   at Kudu.Core.Jobs.BaseJobRunner.InitializeJobInstance(JobBase job, IJobLogger logger) in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Jobs\BaseJobRunner.cs:line 232
   at Kudu.Core.Jobs.TriggeredJobRunner.<>c__DisplayClass10_1.<StartJobRun>b__0(Object _) in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Jobs\TriggeredJobRunner.cs:line 78
```

When I go to the Console and do a `dir` I see plenty of disk space...
[image]

And when I go to Kudu and look at the environment I see this...
[image]

What I'm not sure about is the difference between `D:\home` and `d:\local` b/c I think `Home` has plenty of space, but `local` maybe not?

The code for the app is not large, but it does download some big files from an FTP site, then uncompress them on disk and send them up to the S3 cloud.

So I can see storage being an issue on `local` but `Home` should have plenty.

I can see the files download and uncompress on the `Home` directory in the Console, but does all this happen in the background on `local` first and then get copied over after the app runs or something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE:
I have reviewed this post:
[Azure WebJobs: There is not enough space on the disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30354377/azure-webjobs-there-is-not-enough-space-on-the-disk)
- Seems pretty old, also OP was able to resolve with a higher plan. This did not work for me.

UPDATE: Per recommendation, adding answers to common questions regarding [WebJobs issues](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-WebJobs-issues)...
1) This is a triggered WebJob that is scheduled to run once a day with CRON

2) It is being deployed by publishing directly from inside Visual Studio Pro 2017, settings below.

[image: Publish Settings 1]

[image: Publish Settings 2]

3) It is written in C#.net Core 2.2 as a Console Application

4) I am NOT using the WebJobs SDK

UPDATE 2: Also [posted on GitHub](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/3021)

Comment: Not an answer but a suggestion. Even if you manage to find a solution for your web app, you should use Blobs to store the files, this way if the FTP server gives you a 51GB file tomorrow, you wouldn't have to scale up your web app manually. As far as uncompresion goes, you could use an azure function to do that, this will keep your web app's resources free for actually web requests.

Comment: Difference between `Home` and `Local` can be found here: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#home-directory-access-dhome

Comment: @bit -- unfortunately, the compressed files use a 3rd party tool called (LiteSpeed) (https://www.quest.com/products/litespeed-for-sql-server/) so i have to run a `.exe` process on the disk to extract. luckily the files are fairly consistent, around 500MB each and they extract to 4-5 files which are each around 400MB. this is not much space, even if i have 10 or so files, still well beneath the 50GB limit. i plan to update the code so it deletes them after processing, but still not sure why i'm running into the issue.

Comment: @KenWMSFT -- so per the link, the `Home` drive is `where applications store their content` do u have an idea why i would be getting this error since on the `Home` drive it is showing plenty of free space? (also, seems like that documentation is for the `Web App sandbox` -- is that the same for `WebJobs`?)

Comment: Azure webjobs run in the same web app sandbox.  As for your particular issue, I don't know with the info you provided.  Some of the questions this forum could use to help you can be found here: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-WebJobs-issues

Comment: @KenWMSFT -- i updated my question with answers to the questions in that link.

Comment: Standard sites do get 50GB, however the temp folder limit is different, for details you could refer to this [wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system#temporary-files). So go to your web Diagnose and solve problems->Best Practices->Best Practices for Availability, Performance->Temp File Usage On Workers, check temp usage. Note the limit is the a combined limit of all sites in a service plan.

Comment: And if this is caused by the temp folder limit, maybe you could set `is_in_place` to true to make it won't be copied to temp folder. Check here https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs#webjob-working-directory

Comment: @GeorgeChen -- i'm not entirely clear if ALL the data is copied over each time, but if it is, then we could get to that 11GB limit for sure. that's why i upgraded to the `Standard 1` to avoid the limit. i will try the `is_in_place` setting, but also i tweaked the code to delete the files after processing, so storage is less of an issue anyways.